# How to diff two lists and get net changes

Tags: c#, algorithm, list

I have an object and two lists as follows:

```
    public class MyObject
    {
        public int Key;
        public DateTime Day;
        public decimal Value;
    }        

    List<MyObject> listA = new List<MyObject>()
    {
        new MyObject() { Key = 1, Day = new DateTime(2012, 12, 17), Value = 8 },
        new MyObject() { Key = 1, Day = new DateTime(2012, 12, 18), Value = 8 },
        new MyObject() { Key = 2, Day = new DateTime(2012, 12, 17), Value = 8 },
        new MyObject() { Key = 3, Day = new DateTime(2012, 12, 17), Value = 4 },
        new MyObject() { Key = 4, Day = new DateTime(2012, 12, 17), Value = 4 }
    };

    List<MyObject> listB = new List<MyObject>()
    {
        new MyObject() { Key = 1, Day = new DateTime(2012, 12, 17), Value = 2 },
        new MyObject() { Key = 1, Day = new DateTime(2012, 12, 18), Value = 8 },
        new MyObject() { Key = 3, Day = new DateTime(2012, 12, 17), Value = 8 },
        new MyObject() { Key = 4, Day = new DateTime(2012, 12, 17), Value = 4 },
        new MyObject() { Key = 5, Day = new DateTime(2012, 12, 17), Value = 10 }
    };
```

The results I am looking for are:

```
    List<MyObject> listChanges = new List<MyObject>()
    {
        new MyObject() { Key = 1, Day = new DateTime(2012, 12, 17), Value = -6 },
        new MyObject() { Key = 2, Day = new DateTime(2012, 12, 17), Value = -8 },
        new MyObject() { Key = 3, Day = new DateTime(2012, 12, 17), Value = 4 },
        new MyObject() { Key = 5, Day = new DateTime(2012, 12, 17), Value = 10 }
    };
```

Essentially, I am trying to create a list which contains the changes that would be required to make listA into listB. Thus, while Except, and Intersect from LINQ could be used I don't think they will have the best performance to do such a task as you would still need another comparison to get the difference in the values.

One thought I had is: If I loop through listA, I can remove the item from listA and from listB (if it is found and at this time I can determine the +/- differences). Once I have finished with listA, listB would only contain additions.

**How can I get the change results?**

Comment: This is a perfect opportunity for you to break out the [Stopwatch class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) and test the scenarios you just listed. :)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Do you truly have a performance/optimization issue here? Are you comparing _many thousands_ of entries? If not, then I seriously doubt there will be a performance issue, in which case I would suggest you focus on putting together an easy-to-maintain design. With regards to actual design, perhaps your `MyObject` should have some sort of `Compare` method which indicates if another `MyObject` instance is equal, and if not, what aspects are different.

Comment: John - Thanks for the clarification, sorry about the initial title.

Comment: Chris - I do not have a performance issue just curiosity at this point. I am always trying to see if there is a better/faster way of doing something.  I have implemented an IEqualityComparer for this object type to be used with Except & Intersect in a different scenario, but I am not sure it can be leveraged here (unless except can be modified to return the change object).

Answer (score 0):

how about this :

```
        List<MyObject> listA = new List<MyObject>(){
            new MyObject() { Key = 1, Day = new DateTime(2012, 12, 17), Value = 8 },
            new MyObject() { Key = 2, Day = new DateTime(2012, 12, 17), Value = 8 },
            new MyObject() { Key = 1, Day = new DateTime(2012, 12, 18), Value = 8 },
            new MyObject() { Key = 4, Day = new DateTime(2012, 12, 17), Value = 4 },
            new MyObject() { Key = 3, Day = new DateTime(2012, 12, 17), Value = 4 }
        };

        List<MyObject> listB = new List<MyObject>(){
            new MyObject() { Key = 1, Day = new DateTime(2012, 12, 17), Value = 2 },
            new MyObject() { Key = 3, Day = new DateTime(2012, 12, 17), Value = 8 },
            new MyObject() { Key = 4, Day = new DateTime(2012, 12, 17), Value = 4 },
            new MyObject() { Key = 1, Day = new DateTime(2012, 12, 18), Value = 8 },
            new MyObject() { Key = 5, Day = new DateTime(2012, 12, 17), Value = 10 }
        };
        List<MyObject> listChanges = Comparer(listA, listB);
        MyObject[] hasil = listChanges.ToArray();
        for (int a = 0; a < hasil.Length;a++ ) {
            Console.WriteLine(hasil[a].Key+" "+hasil[a].Day+" "+hasil[a].Value);
        }
```

and the function :

```
    private MyObject[] sort(List<MyObject> input) {
        //sort input with it's key
        MyObject[] gg = input.ToArray();
        for (int a = 0; a < input.Count; a++) {
            for (int b = a + 1; b < input.Count; b++) {
                if (gg[a].Key > gg[b].Key) {
                    MyObject temp = gg[a];
                    gg[a] = gg[b];
                    gg[b] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        //sort input, if key is same => sort the date
        for (int a = 0; a < input.Count; a++) {
            int indStart = a;
            int indEnd = a;
            for (int b = a + 1; b < input.Count; b++) {
                if (gg[a].Key == gg[b].Key) {
                    indEnd++;
                } else {
                    b = input.Count;
                }
            }
            a = indEnd;
            for (int c = indStart; c <= indEnd; c++) {
                for (int d = c + 1; d <= indEnd; d++) {
                    if (gg[c].Day > gg[d].Day) {
                        MyObject temp = gg[c];
                        gg[c] = gg[d];
                        gg[d] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return gg;
    }
    private List<MyObject> Comparer(List<MyObject> listA, List<MyObject> listB) {
        List<MyObject> output = new List<MyObject>();
        //if you sure that the list was sorted, u just remove the sort function
        MyObject[] ff = sort(listA);
        MyObject[] gg = sort(listB);
        Boolean[] masuk = new Boolean[gg.Length];
        //foreach element in listA, search the changes in input
        for (int a = 0; a < listA.Count;a++ ) {
            //find element in input which contains the changes of element in listA
            Boolean ins = false;
            for (int b = 0; b < listB.Count;b++ ) {
                if (masuk[b])
                    continue;
                if (ff[a].Key >= gg[b].Key) {
                    if (ff[a].Key == gg[b].Key && ff[a].Day == gg[b].Day){
                        masuk[b] = true;
                        if (gg[b].Value != ff[a].Value) {
                            output.Add(new MyObject() { Key = gg[b].Key, Day = gg[b].Day, Value = gg[b].Value - ff[a].Value });
                            b = listB.Count;
                        }
                        ins = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    b = listB.Count;
                }
            }
            if (!ins) {
                output.Add(new MyObject() { Key = ff[a].Key, Day = ff[a].Day, Value = -ff[a].Value });
            }
        }
        for (int a = 0; a < gg.Length;a++ ) {
            if(!masuk[a]){
                output.Add(new MyObject() { Key = gg[a].Key, Day = gg[a].Day, Value = gg[a].Value });
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
```

and the output :

```
    1 12/17/2012 12:00:00 AM -6
    2 12/17/2012 12:00:00 AM -8
    3 12/17/2012 12:00:00 AM 4
    5 12/17/2012 12:00:00 AM 10
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would implement an `IEqualityComparer<T>` that checks equality based on both the `Key` and `Day` properties. Then you could use linq as follows:

```
var notInA = listB.Except(listA, myEqualityComparer);
var notInB = listA.Except(listB, myEqualityComparer)
                   .Select(o => {
                      return new MyObject {
                         Key = item.Key,
                         Day = item.Day,
                         Value = item.Value * -1
                      };
                   });
var listA2 = listA.Intersect(listB, myEqualityComparer)
                  .OrderBy(o => o.Key)
                  .ThenBy(o => o.Day);
var listB2 = listB.Intersect(listA, myEqualityComparer)
                  .OrderBy(o => o.Key)
                  .ThenBy(o => o.Day);
var diff = listA2.Zip(listB2, (first,second) => {
   return new MyObject {
     Key = first.Key,
     Day = first.Day,
     Value = second.Value - first.Value
});
diff = diff.Concat(notInA).Concat(notInB);
```

Comment: This doesn't cover "removal" of anything that's not in B. It also relies on the intersection being ordered the same in both A and B.

Comment: The `notInA` variable contains all of the items in B that are not in A. The `Intersect` method calls remove everything in A that is not in B. I updated for ordering, thanks for catching that.

Comment: But everything that is in A but not in B should be present in the output with a negative value, not missing altogether.

Comment: Another good catch. I guess I'm still recuperating from new year's festivities.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. It'll throw an exception if any of your `Key`/`Day` combinations are not unique within either of your inputs.

```
public static IEnumerable<MyObject> GetChanges(
    IEnumerable<MyObject> from, IEnumerable<MyObject> to)
{
    var dict = to.ToDictionary(mo => new { mo.Key, mo.Day });

    // Check that keys are distinct in from, too:
    var throwaway = from.ToDictionary(mo => new { mo.Key, mo.Day });

    // Adjustments of items found in "from"
    foreach (MyObject mo in from)
    {
        var key = new { mo.Key, mo.Day };
        MyObject newVal;
        if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out newVal))
        {
            // Return item indicating adjustment
            yield return new MyObject { 
                Key = mo.Key, Day = mo.Day, Value = newVal.Value - mo.Value };
            dict.Remove(key);
        }
        else
        {
            // Return item indicating removal
            yield return new MyObject {
                Key = mo.Key, Day = mo.Day, Value = -mo.Value };
        }
    }

    // Creation of new items found in "to"
    foreach (MyObject mo in dict.Values)
    {
        // Return item indicating addition
        // (Clone as all our other yields are new objects)
        yield return new MyObject {
            Key = mo.Key, Day = mo.Day, Value = mo.Value };
    }
}
```

You *could* speed this up by removing the uniqueness check on `from` or doing it on-the-fly (try adding each item's key-parts to a `HashSet`), but I don't think you can avoid looping over part of `to` twice - once to build the dictionary, once to return the remainder.